# Option to position(eg. topRight, topBottom, bottomRight, leftCenter etc.) the fancybox(fancyapps - fancybox v5)

Tags: fancybox

I want to set the alignment of fancybox to different position based on requirement.

for example -

- bottomRight : for aligning fancybox on the  right side when it is on the bottom
- bottomCenter : for aligning fancybox on the  center when it is on the bottom
- bottomLeft : for aligning fancybox on the  left side when it is on the bottom

What should be the approach to accomplish this requirement. if someone has any idea/solution please suggest.

thank you.

This is my current workaround for it -

```css
.has-iframe .fancybox__content, .has-map .fancybox__content, .has-pdf .fancybox__content {
            /* bottom right align */
            /* bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            position: absolute; */

            /* bottom left align */
            /* bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            position: absolute; */

            /* top right align */
            /* top: 0;
            right: 0;
            position: absolute; */

            /* top left align */
            /* top: 0;
            left: 0;
            position: absolute; */

            /* bottom center align */
            /* margin: 0 auto;
            bottom: 0;
            position: absolute; */

            /* left align */
            /* left: 0;
            position: absolute; */

            /* right align */
            right: 0;
            position: absolute;
        }
```